# ASP MVC Rotativa (wkhtmltopdf) to Virtual Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa, iis-10

I don't want to raise this as an issue / bug on the git page as I imagine I am simply using the package wrong.

I have an ASP MVC site running on IIS10. Actual folder structure is:

```
x:/
    library/  <-- Physical
    Web Sites/
        Site A/
            Files/  <-- Virtual
        Site B/
        Site C/
```

And using IIS10, I've made a virtual folder called Files under Site A, of which the physical path is X:/library/ (the reason for this is to share resources between sites and to take the content outside of the web-site path).

Users are able to upload / download files to / from the virtual directory fine. I can load images from there without issue also.

However, I cannot seem to get Rotativa to write to the virtual directory from within my application. Obviously command line does not see the virtual directory anyway, but creating a file from cmd to the physical directory works fine.

From within the app though:

`X:/Web Sites/Files/Test.pdf` results in `Unable to write to destination`
`X:/library/Test.pdf` results in `Access to the path is denied` (despite already giving `NETWORK SERVICE` full control of the `library` folder and sub-folders)

The code I am using is:

```
var pdf_output= new ActionAsPdf("Summary", new { id = id }) {
        FileName = String.Format("Summary_{0}.pdf",id.ToString()),
        CustomSwitches = "--print-media-type"
      };
byte[] pdf_data= pdf_output.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(String.Format("xxx",id.ToString()), pdf_data);
```

with a variety of directory path combinations in place of "xxx".

Has anyone had any experience with this before that might show me where I am going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, solved it. I needed to grant the respective Application Pool permission to the physical `library` directory by adding the user `IIS AppPool\Site A`.